# Append Firebase chat messages

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat app and I have a list of all the messages sent between two users in a table view cell. For example, I have four texts in total between the two users and so I have four cells. However, I would like to group the cells so that I only have one cell, because I the loggedInUser is only communicating with one person. No matter what I do, the messages will not append.

```
func loadData(){
if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil{

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

let loggedInUserData = snapshot
if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {

for post in postsDictionary {
    let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    for (id, value) in messages {
        let info = value as! [String: AnyObject]
        if let receiver = info["ReceiverId"] {
        print("\(id): \(receiver)")
       self.messages.Array(value)

        }

    }
    self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
}


}})}
}
```

As of now my app is displaying messages between two users like this:
[image]

I think the issue is in the `self.messages.Array(value)` I just need to append messages between the same two users but I can't find the right code

But I would like for a conversation between two users to be in one cell (append it)[image]

This is what my cell looks like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell


    //Configure the cell


    print(messages[indexPath.row])
    let message = self.messages[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
    if let seconds = message["timestamp"] as? Double {
        let timeStampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        cell.Time.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timeStampDate as Date)
    }



    cell.Message.text = message["text"] as? String
   // cell.SellerName.text = message["ReceiverId"] as? String


  if let imageName =  message["ReceiverId"] as? String {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(imageName)

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
        in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            for post in dictionary {
                let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                for (id, value) in messages {

                cell.SellerName.text = messages["username"] as? String
                    if (messages["uid"] as? String) != nil {
                        let uidPoster = messages["uid"] as? String
                        let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child((uidPoster)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")

                        imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {

                                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                cell.UserPic.image = image

                                cell.UserPic.layer.cornerRadius = 30
                                cell.UserPic.clipsToBounds = true



                            }else {

                                print("Error downloading image:" )


                            }})}

                    self.messages.add(value)
                }
            }


        }

    })
    }

    return cell
}
```

my path to firebase message is:

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child("(self.convoId!)").childByAutoId()

Here is my database structure:[image]

Comment: Offtopic but why would you observe a single event and not child added? This way all old AND new messages will get downloaded.

Comment: @J.Doe it works fine. I don't have a problem with the old and new messages being downloaded

Comment: Please, explain something. You want like when i send 4 messages in sequence they should append to each other to be only one cell?

Comment: Just like a text message in your phone, when you text someone all your chats should be in one cell @VladPulichev

Comment: @juelizabeth I haven't understood you actually:( Please, add a screenshot, what do u mean?

Comment: @VladPulichev i have updated it

Comment: @juelizabeth maybe you should just .queryLimited(toLast: 1) to messages to each chat. And if details opened - load other messages.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? How cells appear in the UI is totally independent of the Array which is independent of how you populate the array. 'Appending' doesn't mean anything in this case. What IS important is how you pull the data from the array and display it. The graphic in the question just below *But I would like for a conversation between two users to be in one cell (append it)* is exactly the same graphic from the image above, just the first cell. What does second graphic show that's different from the first?

Comment: two people are having a conversation. The first graphic shows every message  sent by each user. The second graphic shows the same conversation within one cell. So when I click on the second graphic, I should then see the list of messages between those two users @Jay

Comment: @Jay I have also updated what my cell looks like

Comment: So in your cell, you want to see only the last message from the user? so then when you click on it, it shows the thread of all of messages between the users?

Comment: yes exactly @Jay

Comment: So you don't actually want to append to what's there, you want to overwrite. i.e. replace what's in (array index 0) cell 0 when there's a new message. That's pretty simple with .childAdded. You could just erase the array and add the new message to it (which would always be index 0). Or replace the item at array index 0 with the new one. The suggestion in the posted answer with .queryLimited would work as well. I can't more more specific without seeing your structure.

Comment: @Jay I have posted my database structure is there a way you can edit my post to show exactly what you are talking about It would be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: Ugh. Please post your structure as TEXT please, no images. Images cannot be searched and if we need to use the structure in an answer we have to retype it. You can get your structure via the Firebase dashboard->Three dots on right->Export JSON

Comment: im sorry. I have updated again @Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use a super simple example in my answer.

Given a structure

```
messages
   msg_0
      rec: "uid_0"
      send: "uid_1"
      msg: "msg from uid_0 to uid_1"
   msg_1
      rec: "uid_1"
      send: "uid_0"
      msg: "msg from uid_1 to uid_0"
```

Add a query observer to the messages node watching for any new messages (.childAdded) that have a rec: of uid_0.

```
var messagesArray = [String]()

func watch() {
    let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages")
    let queryRef = messagesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "rec").queryEqual(toValue: "uid_0")

    queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let msgDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let msg = msgDict["msg"] as! String

        self.messagesArray = [] //erases the array
        self.messagesArray.append(msg) //adds this new message at index 0

        print(self.messagesArray) //print is just for example
        //normally call tableView.reloadData() which will refresh
        //  the cells in the tableView and display just once cell with
        //  the latest message in it
    })
}
```

You can extrapolate from this by storing the snapshot or the dictionary in the array so you know the message text and can use the send: user id to look up who sent the message.

If you run this code, the output will be any new message sent to uid_0; only the latest message will be displayed. If you have a tableView with the messagesArray as it's dataSource (which is normally how its done) then the tableView would be refreshed and only ever show the latest message for uid_0.

As a side note, .queryLimited(toLast:) could be leveraged here was well.

Comment: because it is hard to access the convoId node, I am not sure exactly where to put .queryLimited(toLast:)

Comment: @juelizabeth You really don't need to use that with the code I provided - my code is tested, works and provides a solution. Even if you did use .queryLimited, the code is almost identical. Go with with I posted and get it working first and then if you want to change it later you'll have a better understanding of the flow. (what is *convold*?) If my solution helps, be sure to accept it so it can help others!

Answer (score 0):

1) I think, that in your case you should .queryLimited(toLast: 1) to messages to each chat. And if details opened - load other messages.

2) But I have an assumption, that you have wrong database structure. [Check this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)

Here you can find good structure of the database for chat by firebase doc's authors.

Also you can check this old snippets of making chat app: [Link](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd)

Hope it helps

Comment: limiting the query to 1 didn't make a difference, I still got four cells

Comment: i think the issue is in the `self.messages.Array(value)` I just need to append messages between the same two users but I can't find the right code

Comment: @juelizabeth Actually I think it's better to do some researchs in your db structure. But wait, I will think

Comment: I apologize, I think you might have been right on the .queryLimited(toLast: 1) and i didn't put it in the right place. Where exactly should I place it