# Get users messages from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When Users have a conversation, I want the conversations to be displayed in a tableViewController. For example, if User1 sends 10 messages to User2, then I should have one cell in my TableView that displays the last message sent in User1 - User2 conversation. Again, if User1 sends User3 4 messages then User1 should have two tableView cells and User2 and User3 should only have 1 message.
My database looks like this:

```
messages
      hx1DXeMFRU
         -KkVUFuhv7xsYVhnjldV
              ReceiverId: "hx1DX1hW5JZMSmDjwQRUYo3i5Yt2"
              senderId: "eMFRUhfmckTq9cRWNnwIc9mqxxv1"
              text:"hey"
              convoId: hx1DXeMFRU
              timestamp: 1495193736.860723
          -KkVUJG8VPOijCvzMKRf
              ReceiverId: "eMFRUhfmckTq9cRWNnwIc9mqxxv1"
              senderId: "hx1DX1hW5JZMSmDjwQRUYo3i5Yt2"
              text:"Hey how are you?"
              convoId: hx1DXeMFRU
              timestamp: 1495193699.448048
```

I am using the below function to retrieve all messages and view them in a messagesViewController. However, when I try to append the conversation between two unique users, it instead appends all of the messages into one cell. So in my specific example, I should have two cells, one for User1 communicating with User2 and User1 communicating with User3.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import JSQMessagesViewController


class MessagesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    var loggedInUserUid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    var dictDetails: [String:AnyObject]?
    var messages = NSMutableArray()
    var messagesArray = [String]()
    var convoId: String?
    var receiverData: AnyObject?
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

    var senderId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    @IBOutlet var MessageTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.73, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

        self.navigationItem.title = "Messages"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white


        loadData()

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func loadData()
    {
        let uidToFind = loggedInUserUid as String!
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "ReceiverId")
            .queryEqual(toValue: uidToFind).queryLimited(toLast: 1)
            .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

                let msgDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
                let msg = msgDict["ReceiverId"] as! String
                self.messages = []
                self.messages.append(msg)
                self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
            })
    }

      // MARK: - Table view data source

     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if messages.count > 0 {
            tableView.backgroundView = .none;
            tableView.separatorStyle  = .singleLine
            return self.messages.count
        }
        else{
            let noDataLabel: UILabel     = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
            noDataLabel.text          = "No Messages"
            noDataLabel.textColor     = UIColor.lightGray
            noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
            tableView.backgroundView  = noDataLabel
            tableView.separatorStyle  = .none
            return 0
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell


        //Configure the cell


        print(messages[indexPath.row])
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        if let seconds = message["timestamp"] as? Double {
            let timeStampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
            cell.Time.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timeStampDate as Date)
        }



        cell.Message.text = message["text"] as? String


      if let imageName =  message["ReceiverId"] as? String {

            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(imageName)

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
            in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                for post in dictionary {
                    let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    for (id, value) in messages {

                    cell.SellerName.text = messages["username"] as? String
                        if (messages["uid"] as? String) != nil {
                            let uidPoster = messages["uid"] as? String
                            let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child((uidPoster)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")

                            imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {

                                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                    cell.UserPic.image = image

                                    cell.UserPic.layer.cornerRadius = 30
                                    cell.UserPic.clipsToBounds = true



                                }else {

                                }})}
                                          self.messages.add(value)
                    }}}})}

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with your Firebase structure as text, not images. Images are not searchable and if we need to use it in an answer, we have to retype it. You can get the structure from your Firebase Console->Three dots on right->Export JSON.

Comment: It's unclear what *I try to append the conversation between two unique users* means. Why are you appending? Why are you appending to? Once it's appended, what should happen? Why are you loading all of the conversations - if there were 200 it may be an overwhelming UI experience for the user. Please clarify your question and we'll take a look!

Comment: If User1 and User2 have a conversation, the texts are sent to firebase in the structure I provided above. If those two users send 20 messages among themselves, then I will like to get the last message sent between those two users and display it in a tableviewcell. If one of the User1 sends 4 messages to another user3, then I would like again to get the last message sent between those users and display it in the tableview. So now user1 has two tableview cells, user2 has 1 and User3 has 1 tableviewcell. @Jay

Comment: If you are only interested in the last message, then why *append* messages? You only want the last one so a new message would *replace* an existing message in the UI. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct. I was appending the messages because I found a tutorial that was doing that so I assumed you have to append the messages in order to get the last message sent @Jay

Comment: @Jay How will I go about implementing this?

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same I gave two days ago. Try implementing that and see where you get stuck and let us know so we can help! [Append Firebase chat messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070005/append-firebase-chat-messages/44077462#44077462).

Comment: instead of getting the last text. I am getting the first text sent by the logged in user and all the messages regardless of who is sending it is appending into one cell @Jay

Comment: Remember that observe .childAdded iterates over all the children one at a time and leaves and observer in place for any newly added nodes. That's probably what you are experiencing. You need to be using a query as shown in the linked answer to limit the nodes to just one user. You may also want to leverage limitedToLast as well. I would suggest updating this question with your current code so we can take a look at what you've done so far. The code posted in this question definitely won't work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jay I have updated my code but now no messages are displayed at all in  my tableview

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code in the question is this

```
queryEqual(toValue: "senderId")
```

That query is going to query the messages/ReceiverId nodes that have a value of "senderId" (literally the string senderId). It needs to query for the actual uid instead.

```
func loadData()
{
   let uidToFind = "hx1DX1hW5JZMSmDjwQRUYo3i5Yt2"
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
                         .queryOrdered(byChild: "ReceiverId")
                         .queryEqual(toValue: uidToFind)
                         .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

      let msgDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
      let msg = msgDict["ReceiverId"] as! String
      self.messages = []
      self.messages.append(msg)
      self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
   })
}
```

I will stress that while this code works, it's iterating over all of the child nodes matching ReceiverId = uid, loading them one at a time and leaving an observer for any new child nodes added afterwards.

This is a good thing as it allows you to populate an array with multiple values as well as attaching a listener for new values.

However, if you are really only interested in the most recent post, a better direction would be to use queryLimitedToLast(1) which will only return the last node that matches the query.

Something like

```
var messages = [String]()
func loadData()
{
   let uidToFind = "hx1DX1hW5JZMSmDjwQRUYo3i5Yt2"
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
                         .queryOrdered(byChild: "ReceiverId")
                         .queryEqual(toValue: uidToFind)
                         .queryLimited(toLast: 1)
                         .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

      let msgDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
      let msg = msgDict["ReceiverId"] as! String
      self.messages = []
      self.messages.append(msg)
      //self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
      print(self.messages) //this will print the last msg and any new msgs
   })
}
```

Comment: This isn't working. I tried all day but it is not working. I have updated my database to include convoId. Hopefully, now it will only append messages with the same convoId and output the last message

Comment: @juelizabeth Well, that code comes (copy and paste) straight from a brand new project with an identical Firebase structure. If it's not working for you, either you have a typo somewhere or your database is not being initialized - or possibly a rule is in place that preventing it from working. I don't know which it is but the code definitely works.

Comment: I have updated my code to what my entire view controller looks like. I don't want to search for a specific user messages. That's why I included the convoId so that messages among two users will have their own unique Ids and would able to be appended through that

Comment: @juelizabeth I think you do want to search for specific user messages. Actually, let's re-phrase that; the logged in user wants to be notified if there are any messages for them. i.e. user uid_1 logs in - the app should notify them of any messages that are for him. So, the query would be observing any message nodes where ReceivedId is uid_1, this user. I wouldn't think that uid_1 would want to be notified of messages between uid_2 and uid_3, right?

Comment: @juelizabeth Excellent! Then the code in my answer does exactly that - assign the current uid of the logged in user to the uidToFind var and when that user logs in, they will receive events any time a message is posted that ReceiverId is their uid!

Comment: so I ran it again and I realized I was getting this warning: `Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "ReceiverId" at /messages to your security rules for better performance` and so I included this: `"messages": {
    ".indexOn": "ReceiverId",
    }` into my security rules but I still am not receiving any messages

Comment: can you please take a look at my entire view controller, I honestly don't know what ! am doing wrong

Comment: @juelizabeth Looking at the code in your question, it won't build. There are numerous typing and logic errors. For example, *self.messages.add* should be *self.messages.append*. I updated your code. Also, the messagesArray is defined as an array of Strings. Therefore, this assignment *let message = self.messages[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]* isn't valid as the elements in the array are not dictionaries. You need to simplify. I would suggest commenting out all of that code and replacing it with what's in my answer. Run it to see it works. Then you can re-build your code from there.

Comment: @juelizabeth Also, I created a new project and copy/pasted my code and it worked with no changes. Note that I commented out the tableview refresh and substituted in the print to help narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145144/discussion-between-juelizabeth-and-jay).